# Access router firmware files / override them

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, firmware, default-settings

Hi i recently bought a router "LTE 4G USB MODEM with Wi-Fi HotSpot" It's working properly but unfortunately it's firmawe does not have an option to turn the Wi-Fi hotspot off (I would like to mainly use it as a usb), so i begun wondering if i can somehow replace the firmware or access the settings files to turn it off. Any ideas to achive that are appreciated.

Edit:
This is the modem i bought https://allegro.pl/oferta/modem-usb-lte-4g-rebel-bezprzewodowy-13957661493 There are a lot of them on this site, they come from china. Thats all information i have

The modem does have a settings page at an ip adress 192.168.100.1. The problem is that there is no way in the settings to turn the Wi-Fi off (pic) https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbMQy.png

The settings interface does not contain any option to "update" the device.

I found the manufacturer and model  Qualcomm Technology Model   V2.3.7

I tried inputing an invalid SSID (with ?) the device buggs out and stops transfering data, fortunately there is a factory boot button on the device so I reset it.

Comment: What's the make and model? Usually the settings page is in either 192.168.0.0, 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.0 or 192.168.1.1. As for firmware updates, they have to be provided by the manufacturer, and are usually installed through said settings interface.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Technically what you ask is *may be* possible, but the level of technical expertise in HW hacking is no small curve. With a make and model of the modem, there is maybe a method by which  to do so. However it is possible since it is the devices core function, that the FW developers never considered this use case.